# Another proof of Jensen’s Inequality (finite form)

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, jensen-inequality

I am reading through Jensen’s inequality and its proofs. I want to find an alternate proof to the tangent line proof.

My attempt:

If $f(x)$ is a convex function, then $\{x_{i},f(x_{i})\}\ ,\ i=1,2,...,n$ are vertices of a convex $n$ - gon, the interior of which is never below $f(x)$.

For $a_{i}\geq 0\ , \ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}}=1$, the $n$ - gon’s interior point $\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}x_{i}}\ , \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}f(x_{i})}\right\}$ is never below $\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}x_{i}}\ ,f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}x_{i}}\right)\right\}$.

This is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}f(x_{i})}\geq f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}x_{i}}\right)$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: How do you establish the statement after "My Attempt:"? How do you define a convex function?

Comment: @copper.hat I define convex function as function with positive second derivative here.

Comment: Then how do you establish the statement after "My Attempt:"

Comment: @copper.hat i use the fact that if i make $n$ - gon using points on the function’s graph, internal angle $\angle ABC < 180$ if $A,B,C$ are consecutive vertices, thus the $n$ - gon is convex.

Comment: Is your domain the real line here?

Comment: @copper.hat the domain is real number and function sir

Comment: Well, let me see, the proof is fine, given what you have given as a definition, however, the usual definition is either that the epigraph is convex or the function satisfies $f(tx+(1-t)y) \le t f(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: It might be a good idea to write down the question completely. For example:
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable with $f''(x) > 0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
Prove that Jensen's inequality holds for $f$.
For the proof, you first need to prove that $(x_i, f(x_i), i=1, 2, \cdots, n$ are vertices of a convex $n$-gon
from the hypothesis $f''(x) > 0$.